# Show thumbnail pager strip at the bottom of PDF View

Tags: java, android, pdf, thumbnails

I want to show thumbnail pager strip at the bottom of the pdf view which will contain thumbnail images of all pages in the PDF file [as shown in the image below in yellow highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DpKM.png) . I am using Android PDF View Library by JoanZapata available at [GitHub](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview). Plzz help.

Comment: Almost the exact same question with the exact same screenshot was asked 40 minutes ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607390/i-want-to-add-thumbnails-in-pdf-file ...

Answer (score 0):

Convert your pdf to images and display it in your horizontal listview at bottom as shown in image using 
Convert pdf to images : [Use this](https://github.com/katjas/PDFrenderer)

Comment: Can't get it. Its java project. I am unable to import it in Android Studio. can you send me any other example plz?